# How can I add swipe actions to UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I would like to have a swipe gesture that would display actions like so:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

I looked around SO, Google and the Apple Docs for a way to achieve this without much success. I am using a UICollectionView, but I've just realized that a UITableView would also do the trick.

Comment: I'd suggest you replace your collection view with a table view, since it has all these kind of features baked into it.

Comment: http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-swipe-actions-for-uitableviewcell-in-swift/